# create a regex that knows balanced parenthesis with maximum depth of 5

Tags: python, regex, expression, parentheses

I have a problem with a regex, it is supposed to match if the depth is between 1 or 5, for example it should match with “()()()”, “((((()))))”, “(()((()))())” and not match with  “())()”, “(((((())))))” och “(x)”.
I have this

```
    pattern = '^(?:\(\)|\(\((?:\(\)|[^()])*\)\)){0,5}$'
    return pattern
```

-waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Regular expressions are not good for detecting balanced patterns, unless you use the recursion operator.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: Read [Regular Expression Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)

Comment: This problem can be solved easily with a loop, which is much more efficient than regex. Are you sure that you really want a pure regex solution?

Comment: yes it needs to be a regex solution, but i suppose it isnt possible to have a loop for a regex 'function'?

Comment: that link was helpful but didnt include python flavor, how would you rewrite this    \((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)   in python?

Comment: The built-in `re` module doesn't support recursion so you will have to install [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) or a similar package/library/whatever.

Comment: @Barmar Can you limit the recursion depth with that?

Comment: @KellyBundy Good question, I suspect not, but I haven't used it before.

Comment: Do you have to do this using regex? If it's an assignment, surely the instructor has taught the operations you need to use. This is a pretty advanced, non-standard feature of regex.

Comment: @Barmar You're still talking about recursion, right? I don't think that's intended.

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't think you can do this without recursion, but maybe limiting the levels makes it possible. If you know how to do it, post an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Well it's clearly a regular language, a DFA is trivial. I don't remember how to convert a DFA to a regular expression, though :-)

Comment: Partially a regex solution https://ideone.com/odNIAM

Comment: @Kelly Bundy - Just because a language is regular does not mean the DFA equivalent is trivial. We would need an infinite number of states, just for a simple regular language of matching parentheses (of unlimited depth). And then "even more" 8-), to do anything else.

Comment: @Eureka You misunderstood, and apparently also ignored the answers. It's the other way around: A DFA is trivial, which means the language is clearly regular. We don't need an infinite number of states. We only need to be able to count up to 5. If we ever reach depth 6, we go to an error state and remain there. I even show a DFA (with eight states) in my answer. I don't understand why you guys keep talking about unlimited depth. That isn't what the question is about.

Comment: Agreed - I misunderstood because I read your comment as "Well it's clearly a regular language, _and therefore_ a DFA is trivial." The "therefore" would be incorrect, but you didn't say or mean that. Apols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it has to be a single expression, you could use multiple re.sub to replace "()" with empty strings five times over.  This should result in an empty string if all parentheses match up to 5 level deep:

```
import re

def parMatch(S):
    oc = r"\(\)"
    return not re.sub(oc,"",re.sub(oc,"",re.sub(oc,"",re.sub(oc,"",re.sub(oc,"",S)))))
```

output:

```
tests = ["()()()", "((((()))))", "(()((()))())","())()", "(((((())))))","(x)"]
for S in tests:
    print(S,parMatch(S))

()()() True
((((())))) True
(()((()))()) True
())() False
(((((()))))) False
(x) False
```

*obviously, this approach does not require regular expressions at all so it's probably not what is expected of you*

If you need it to be a single expression, you could nest multiple non-capturing groups in a recurring(nested) pattern expecting a starting parenthesis, a valid pairing repeated 0-n times, followed by a closing parenthesis. Make the outer group repeatable at least once and spanning the whole string (`^(` ... `)+$`):

```
def parMatch(S):
    oc = r"^(\((?:\((?:\((?:\((?:\(\))*\))*\))*\))*\))+$"
    return bool(re.match(oc,S))
```

The recurring pattern is `\((?:`...`)*\)` which you nest within itself 5 levels deep ending with `\(\)` for the innermost matching parentheses.

Note that non-capturing groups are just to avoid getting multiple entries in the match object.  Since you're only looking for True/False, and not the extracted string itself, it would probably work with capturing groups as well: `r"^(\((\((\((\((\(\))*\))*\))*\))*\))+$"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions for balanced `<` and `>` instead, as that's easier to read/write:

```
(<>|<(<>|<(<>|<(<>|<(<>)+>)+>)+>)+>)+

(<((<((<((<((<>)+)?>)+)?>)+)?>)+)?>)+
```

And the same but with `<` and `>` replaced with `\(` and `\)`:

```
(\(\)|\((\(\)|\((\(\)|\((\(\)|\((\(\))+\))+\))+\))+\))+

(\(((\(((\(((\(((\(\))+)?\))+)?\))+)?\))+)?\))+
```

I built them by starting with a pattern for depth 1, then using it to build a pattern for depths 1 to 2, then using that for a pattern for depths 1 to 3, and so on, up to 5:

```py
p = r'(<>)+'
for _ in range(4):
  # p = r'(<>|<p>)+'.replace('p', p)
    p = r'(<(p)?>)+'.replace('p', p)
pattern = p.replace('<', r'\(').replace('>', r'\)')

print(p)
print(pattern)
```

Testing it:

```
import re

good = "()()()", "((((()))))", "(()((()))())"
bad = "())()", "(((((())))))", "(x)"

for s in good:
    print(re.fullmatch(pattern, s))

for s in bad:
    print(re.fullmatch(pattern, s))
```

Test results ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZFLbgIxDEDFNqewhkVidWDFAqGBXqRSlUIGRhoSywSpldqTdMOmPVRPUwfzW7DAUSR_nh3H_v6lj7xJ8XD42ed2NP0bfBHMga1rFvhkTZsYXqGLwD6ug5vgzAAM4cJ8NlS4MQfq_TI4S7YGQoHgAjnC57sQ-ZwDR8HoGmskxvbFWbz6FupDi8YQdzG7kq2K1pCA6baUOAMHY9YpraRs5bCcqhatCBZRC9WUW5k3f4JvWYXVfhfoOIpdGUUpPtMfHlvgMG73fb_1ebk591PDDvEmR554KEW3cFrGeSn_)):

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='()()()'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='((((()))))'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='(()((()))())'>
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter pattern found a different way than in my fist answer:

```
With <>:  (<(<(<(<(<>)*>)*>)*>)*>)+
With ():  (\((\((\((\((\(\))*\))*\))*\))*\))+
```

First I wrote a DFA (using `a` and `b` instead of parentheses):

[image: DFA]

`si` is the initial state, `se` is an error state, and `s0` to `s5` tell how many parentheses are currently open (0 to 5).

That image was created by [FSM2Regex](https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/) when I entered this DFA:

```
#states
si
s0
s1
s2
s3
s4
s5
se
#initial
si
#accepting
s0
#alphabet
a
b
#transitions
si:a>s1
si:b>se
s0:a>s1
s0:b>se
s1:a>s2
s1:b>s0
s2:a>s3
s2:b>s1
s3:a>s4
s3:b>s2
s4:a>s5
s4:b>s3
s5:a>se
s5:b>s4
se:a>se
se:b>se
```

It also gave me this pattern:

```
a(a(a(a(ab)*b)*b)*b)*(b+b(a(a(a(a(ab)*b)*b)*b)*b)*($+a(a(a(a(ab)*b)*b)*b)*b))
```

Note that `$` means the empty string there and `+` means alternation. It doesn't use `+` to mean "one or more of the previous thing", so I wrote the short pattern at the top of this answer myself after seeing this.